# How can I generate a swagger definition file only for my model

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I have some java objects Id like to create a swagger definition for. I dont expose controllers using the api model. Its just java models I need "described" so other projects in other languages can autogenerate the same model.

I have tried to setup a maven project and tried to genereate the swagger definition using
com.github.kongchen

But I just get an empty swagger definition file. My java object is not added as a definition under definitions in my swagger file.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is an other plugin that do this you can try it in order to solve your problem

https://github.com/conorroche/swagger-doclet